# Is it safe to use a hidden input form comment id?

Tags: php, html, hidden-field, hiddenfield

I am developing a facebook similar wall, and im a bit corious, is it safe to use a hidden input storing the stream id?

So in my db for comments i have 4 fields, `the comment id, stream id, user id, and comment text` stream id is for to locate which wall post has comment, and i would store this in a hidden input for the form.

is it safe? or i should think a nother idea?

Thank you

Comment: Never trust the client. So as long as you validate your ID, no harm in passing it along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to identify somehow what wall user post at, so you have to pass that parameter either in GET parameters or other way (using POST at your case). I don't think anything is wrong with this. If someone can to a damage knowing that data then you have a security problem  in your app.

Level of security by passing that data through hidden input or through GET parameter is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way I can think of solving this problem is by using a [session store](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) if possible, unless I'm misunderstanding something.